# "Logging output too large. Truncating output..."

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, airtable

I'm trying to pull data from Airtable using Apps Scripts but all of it doesn't transfer over due to size. What do I need to add/change in order for it work?

```
function importCA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ca_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CA")
  var ca = getCA(); 
  ca_sheet.getRange(1,1, ca.length, ca[00].length).setValues(ca)
}

function getCA() {
  var ca = requestAirtable();
  //console.log("ca: ", ca)
  var ca_info = []
  ca_info.push(["Name", "Emails", "Districts", "Job Title", "Course", "Completed", "Start Dates"])
  for(i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
   var fields = ca[i].fields;
   ca_info.push([
     fields.Name,
     fields.Emails,
     fields.Districts,
     fields.Title,
     fields.Course,
     fields.Completed,
     fields.StartDates,

   ])
  }
  console.log("CA ", ca_info)
  return ca_info;
}

function requestAirtable() {
  var url = "[removed]"
  var headers ={
    "Authorization": "[removed]",
    "Content-type" : "application/json"
  }
  var options = {
    headers: headers,
    method: "GET"
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  var result = JSON.parse(response);console.log("result: ", result)

return result.records
}
```

I tried to altering the line:

```
for(i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to log the output in the console?

Comment: Log it to a file

Answer (score 0):

If you must log it to console, you could always log it while you are pushing it to the array instead of trying to log the entire array later.

```
console.log(ca_info.push([
    fields.Name,
    fields.Emails,
    fields.Districts,
    fields.Title,
    fields.Course,
    fields.Completed,
    fields.StartDates
   ])
```